# Grails v3.1.4 specify encrypted password for mongodb connection

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb

```
---
grails:
    mongodb:
        host: "localhost"
        port: 27017
        databaseName: "dbName"
        username: "user"
        password: "encryptedPassword"
---
```

How do I decrypt the password before it is used to make connection to MongoDB? The reason being that I don't need to specify plain-text password in my configuration.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: My question was how to specify encrypted password in my application.yml file and somehow decrypt it when the connection to MongoDB is established (inside the code).

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting a password is **security through obscurity**, and could be hacked easily.
I would recommend you using either external config file or system environment variable.

Another advantage of this approach is the fact that you don't need to recompile/modify your war every time you change the password.

Comment: We specify password in a config file only. It does not require a code recompilation, just server restart should suffice. Anyhow, putting encrypted password is still better than plain-text password in config file. If the encryption technique used to encrypt the password is strong, I don't see any reason as to why it is such a bad approach.